High cpu from irq\9-acpi ubuntu server 24.04.1
Fresh install on one of my older machines (2016?),
connected via ssh.

htop shows high cpu usage on a single core (96-100%)
dstat -v --top-cpu shows irq/9-acpi

This is the only machine having this issue. Can someone point me in the right direction to figure out why this is happening?
Specs:

Intel Pentium Processor J4205
15GB ram
250GB SSD


solved... reinstalled and the issue has resolved itself
